# Can't install Mono.Android.Platform.apk on emulator

Tags: android, msbuild, android-emulator, xamarin, xamarin.android

I can no longer install Mono on the emulator, it complains that the device it out of space.

- I have tried using the "Wipte user data" checkbox.
- I have tried making the SD card size bigger.
- I have tried creating a new emulator.

Any ideas?

Getting package list from device

Installing shared runtime package on device

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
Success
84 KB/s (25857266 bytes in 297.291s)
Installing the platform framework
Failed to copy 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\Novell\\platforms\\android-8\\Mono.Android.Platform.apk' to '/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.apk': No space left on device
Failed to install the platform framework
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you starting the emulator yourself or letting the Mono tools start it for you? If you're starting it yourself, the default settings are much too small to install the tools. If you want to start it yourself, you can specify a larger partition size like this:

```
emulator.exe -avd NameOfYourEmulator -partition-size 512
```

More details are available in [Xamarin's docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/command_line_emulator).

Comment: The Mono tools can't start the emulator on my computer due to some bugs in MonoDevelop. I was using the AVD manager, but that doesn't seem to have a partition-size option.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Annoying though, I wish the Mono tools weren't so buggy.